# Raspberry Pi: температура CPU в screen

Tags: железо, raspberry-pi, raspbian, gnu-screen

Появилась идея выводить температуру CPU Raspberry Pi в нижней строке screen. Сейчас содержимое файла .screenrc следующее:

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ~/.screenrc: executed by screen for user settings
# $Revision: 2.10 (CentOS Edition by Wakko Warner) $
# $Comment: Any comments please send to wakko@acmelabs.spb.ru $
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------

  caption always "%{= 45}%{+b w}Screen: %n | %h %=%t %c"
  hardstatus alwayslastline "%-Lw%{= BW}%50>%n%f* %t%{-}%+Lw%<"
#  hardstatus string "[screen %n%?: %t%?] %h"
  defshell -bash
  shell -$SHELL

# VARIABLES
# ===============================================================
# Automatically detach on hangup.
  autodetach on                         # default: on
# Don't display the copyright page
  startup_message off                   # default: on
# Affects the copying of text regions
  crlf off                              # default: off
# Change default scrollback value for new windows
  defscrollback 1000                    # default: 100
# Define the time that all windows monitored for silence should
# wait before displaying a message. Default 30 seconds.
  silencewait 15                        # default: 30
# UTF-8 support
  defutf8 on
# PuTTY tweaks
  termcapinfo xterm* ti@:te@
  termcapinfo xterm ti@:te@

# STARTUP SCREENS
# ===============================================================
# Uncomment one/some following lines to automatically let
# SCREEN start some programs in the given window numbers:
# screen -t IRC         0 irssi
# screen -t EDIT        1 vim
# screen -t GOOGLE      2 links http://www.google.com
# screen -t NEWS        3 slrn
# screen -t WWW         4 links http://rt.com
#  screen -t HTOP       0 htop
#  screen -t BASH       1
#  screen -t F3         2
#  screen -t F4         3
#  screen -t F5         4
#  screen -t F6         5
#  screen -t F7         6
#  screen -t F8         7
#  screen -t F9         8
#  screen -t F10        9
#  select 1
```

Как я понимаю, в строку `hardstatus alwayslastline` нужно добавить `vcgencmd measure_temp`. Но выводиться сама команда, а не её результат.

Answer (score 0):

> Как я понимаю, в строку hardstatus alwayslastline нужно добавить vcgencmd measure_temp.

нет, в эту строку надо вставить отсылку к backtick-команде. синтаксис отсылки (знак процента и знак обратной кавычки — часть синтаксиса):

```
%идентификатор`
```

синтаксис backtick-команды:

```
backtick идентификатор lifespan autorefresh команда с аргументами ...
```

- `идентификатор` — просто уникальное произвольное число, на которое можно сослаться внутри строки `hardstatus`. например, `0`. или `12345`.
- `lifespan` (время жизни) — время (в секундах), в течение которого результат команды считается действительным. после его истечения команда будет выполнена вновь.
- `autorefresh` (авто-обновление) — интервал (в секундах), через который обновляется отображаемое содержимое `hardstatus` (ну и `caption`, где тоже можно использовать отсылку к backtick-команде).

  имеет ли смысл указывать в  `lifespan` и `autorefresh` разные значения, я так и не понял. думаю, по совету [отсюда](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/10950), можно использовать одно и то же значение.

пример:

```
backtick 222 1 1 date -u
hardstatus alwayslastline 'время в utc: %222` и ещё какая-нибудь информация'
```

здесь описан запуск команды `date -u` каждую секунду. отображаться её вывод будет вместо вот этих символов:

```
%222`
```

обратите внимание, что в строке `hardstatus` сразу после идентификатора backtick-команды должна стоять обратная кавычка (по-английски "backtick", что как бы намекает на происхождение названия описываемой команды). такой вот синтаксис, чтобы gnu/screen при парсинге конф. файла (точнее, содержимого строки `hardstatus`/`caption`) мог понять, где именно заканчивается идентификатор-отсылка к соответствующей backtick-команде (их, кстати, можно описать и несколько в одном конф. файле, главное, чтобы идентификаторы были уникальными).